# How to locate random id generated by a modal?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I was testing my website using RF. The problem is, every time the modal is opened, a different id(locator) will be set on the textbox that I want to input my text. How do you get value of this locator?

I was supposed to try ***Get Element Attribute*** but then it cannot support my problem since it still requires a specific locator.

Comment: Spend some time to read this one. [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If it was suggested that you get the element attribute, it meant that you should use an xpath locator that contains, among other possible values, the attribute value you're looking for.  When elements don't have ID's or have dynamic ID's, you have to use other means via xpath, or name, partial link text, etc. to locate the element.  We can't help you without any example HTML code in your original post.

Comment: If you can send the url I might be able to make something work.  I have done this successfully by pulling the whole html and parsing through it.

Answer (score 0):

In ROBOT Framework (RF), the locator can be accessed by several ways. Please refer and read this link: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html

The most common way to access the locator is by id such as :

```
Input Text  id:username # Element with id 'username'.
Input Text  id:password # Element with id 'password'. you can also use 'Input Password' keyword.
```

However, if the 'id' element is so dynamic which it keep changing, then the best alternative is to use either **ABSOLUTE XPATH expression** or **CSS selectors**. Install the XPATH add-on in your web browser. For firefox, just install ChroPath.

Then, get the **ABSOLUTE** Xpath element of that username & password text box. Let's assume we know the absolute xpath expression already, so in ROBOT, you can write like below.

```
${login_absolute_xpath}=  Set Variable   xpath=/html[1]//div[7]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]
${password_absolute_xpath}=  Set Variable   xpath=/html[1]//div[7]/form[1]/div[2]/input[1]

Wait Until Page Contains Element   xpath=${login_absolute_xpath}
Input Text   xpath=${login_absolute_xpath}
Input Text   xpath=${password_absolute_xpath}
...
```

This should works. Please let me know if this helps.